# QGIS Short route points with fixed start and end

Tags: qgis, routing

I need to calculate the shortest/fastest route, distance travel, etc for a group of points with fixed and specified start and end point.
Start/end points could be different or the same.

I tried with several plugins but none let me specified the start/end points here my problem.

I have one layer with the point and other layer with the start/end points.

[image: Points in the route]

How can I do this?

Comment: Please be more precise as to what you are trying to achieve (which points matter, how do you plan on handing them to the tool, etc) and what you tried so far.

Comment: Does this help? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/439959/88814