# how could I calculate the shortest distance between points showing the distance in each different route?

Tags: network-analyst, cost-path, shortest-path, points-to-line, path

I want to do a network analysis using any plugin, but the main problem is that I want to get the shortest distance between two points, but it must give me the distance in each route (in my case they are tracks, rivers and trails) too. Network Analysis or QNEAT3 only give me a total distance without make a differentiation about each route.

In the first or second images are a excel format that I would want. In each case, they are the shortest distance

[image]

[image]

The third and fourth image show my layers. Black line is the main tracks, sky blue lines are rivers (in this case it doesn't show trails). They are in a join layer. The green points are id_point_start. The red point is the id_point_final

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you simply split your routes vector layer into three separate layers, rivers, trails, and tracks, then run whatever algorithm you choose on each?

Comment: Hello, @Micha . I splitted each route but I don't know how to work with them to have the shortest path. I found this link [Calculation of the distance between intersecting lines, but according to existing lines](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/439956/calculation-of-the-distance-between-intersecting-lines-but-according-to-existin/439959#439959) , but I don't know how to put each option. Recently, I startet to work with QGIS I don't have a lot of experience.